# How the okd/openshift cluster can be used by multiple users simultaneously?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3, okd

Problem Scenario:
OKD cluster is having two cluster-admins: User1 and User2.

If User1 connects to cluster using ssh and performs `oc login` and parallely User2 connects to the same cluster with new ssh session and performs `oc login`.

Now when User1 checks `oc whoami` the result will be `User2` (which is desired to have `User1`).  This will create problems like User1 operations(ex:deployements) to clash with User2.

How can this problem be eliminated so that two users can parallelly use the cluster?

Note: Both User1 and User2 are configured with LDAP, is this creating problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this problem be eliminated so that two users can parallelly use the cluster?

AFAIK, the OKD session is saved in $HOME/.kube/config by default. So it depends on a OS account session. If you'd like to use  at the same time, then you should use different OS account each other. OR you should run oc login --config context_file_path per each execution for saving session to different context file. Refer [Loading and Merging Rules](https://docs.okd.io/latest/cli_reference/manage_cli_profiles.html#loading-and-merging-rules)
 for more details.

> Note: Both User1 and User2 are configured with LDAP, is this creating problem?

No. Identity provider configuration does not affect this.

Comment: with ```oc login --config context_file_path``` if i login then for all the oc operations/commands i need to pass config parameter right? Is it possible to set the config to particular context file once so that  user need not bother about passing extra arguement-config with other oc commands

Comment: You mean how to use oc CLI without "--config" with referring  each context, right ? If it's right, you can use `KUBECONFIG=each_user_context_file_path`. Before using oc CLI, define this env for each user session. Then oc CLI consider this env without `--config`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not share user accounts in this way. Each person who is logging in to the cluster should using a command-line client be doing so under their own linux uid against their own home directory. Sharing user accounts is a security vulnerability and removes your ability to track who is doing what.

`kubectl` and `oc` take this as a prerequisite, which is why you're running into this issue.